# Is there a way to get the types of a functions arguments?

Tags: python, types, arguments

Let's say we have a function `foo(a, b)` that is part of the public API of a python module.
Is there any way to query the types of `a` and `b` that the function expects?
I know that I can get the number of arguments and their default values via the `inspect` module, but is there any type information available?

Comment: No, not by default. You should trust your programmers or fail as early as possible in your function. Also, document your public API.

Comment: Check the docstring of the function with `foo.__doc__`  That should have the information you're looking for, but there's no guarantee.  The problem is that Python doesn't force variables into a certain type.  So you can try to pass a string into `sqrt`, for example, and nothing will thow an error until runtime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is a dynamically typed language, so no; a function should *document* their expectations instead.

Python 3.5 and newer support [*optional* type hinting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/); if the library uses type hints, then you can query this information with the [`typing.get_type_hints()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) to access that information programatically.

Generally, Python functions should accept objects that implement *expected functionality*, not specific types. If your function iterates over a sequence to extract strings, then it should be documented as accepting (in type hinting terms) a `Iterable[str]` object, not a list or tuple or other specific type.

Comment: Additionally, it's not the *type* of an argument but rather its available/implemented *methods* that make it suitable as an argument for a specific function, since python uses **duck-typing**.